# How do I report a typo on the Unity website?

Tags: unity

at http://unity.ubuntu.com/about/

A powerful desktop and netbook environment things brings consistency and elegance to the Ubuntu experience.

I suggest "things" has to go in "things brings"

Answer (score 2):

Bugs on the Ubuntu Website can be reported directly in Launchpad:

- https://launchpad.net/ubuntu
- https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-website-content

No need to file it this time, I've corrected the typo, thanks!